# SWF won't load on Chrome but will on Firefox

Tags: apache-flex, load, flash, swfobject

Hi I am experiencing performance issues with an SWF which has been generated by Flash Builder 4.5.

The SWF will not run in Chrome but will on Firefox on my own machine - a Macbook Pro running Mountain Lion, and will not run in any browser currently on a separate MSI netbook, which the application is going to be running on from here-in.

Has anybody any ideas? I originally experienced this issue when trying to use SharedObject, but I fixed an early bug with this and it resumed it's normal performance thereafter.

The major issue I am having obviously is that the swf will not run on the MSI netbook, even though flash is installed (I can view all other flash content)

Conor

-- EDIT --

By using the standalone flash debugger I have found out that the swf was in the wrong security sandbox. To place it in the correct sandbox, I have had to create a directory called FlashPlayerTrust and then created a .CFG file in this directory with the file URL for the SWF included. I then had to refresh the cache on the browser but everything worked fine afterwards.

Comment: Does it really not load or does it crash on startup?

Comment: I've run it in the standalone debug exe on the netbook now and I am getting this error: Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources I've tried setting the global security settings here: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html but it has had no effect

Comment: Which flash player versions on chrome and firefox ?

Comment: I've been investigating this further. I am connecting to a socket in the app and therefore I need to set the app's sandbox to be trusted, but I can't find where I do it on the netbook. God I hate windows :)

Comment: I think that I may need to update the flashplayertrust directory but I can't find the FlashPlayerTrust directory on the machine in question. Anyone ever come across this issue with Windows 7?